# TFS Build Machine Test method errors out on build machine

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, build-process

Here is my unit test code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetMyAttachmentTest()
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(
        Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Common/MyFiles/", "*.*");

     .... do some thing with the files...
}
```

On TFS build machine, when I run my unit test, I am getting the following error:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 
'C:\Builds\4\30 my folder v1.0\myfolder1\TestResults\SCMTFSService_MyBuildServer 2013-01-16 18_06_52_Any CPU_Release\Out\Common\MySpecialFiles\'.
```

When I look into the drop folder in TFS, I see that my files are deployed into the following folder:

```
\\MyBuildServer\Builds\MyFolder\MySolution_20130116.5\Common\MySpecialFiles
```

Inside my unit test code, I get my files as follows:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(
    Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Common/MySpecialFiles/", "*.*");
```

Is there a way when my unit test runs on TFS build machine that it can look into the files in the deployed `Common\MySpecialFiles`?

Comment: Can you post your unit test code(including attributes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit vague.  In the past, I've had issues with unit tests executing in temp locations.  This can be problematic with dynamic paths such as `GetCurrentDirectory()`.  When the the temp directory changes/clears, files can be "lost".

Instead of using a dynamic path, setup a network share with appropriate permissions.  I recommend storing the path to this network share a config file or the DB so that it can be updated without a code push.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the location of the files in an appSettings item in the app.config/web.config file? That will make it easy to change it to match your environment whether it's local, a build server or a deployed environment.

Otherwise, you will have to set the current directory to        **\MyBuildServer\Builds\MyFolder\MySolution_20130116.5** before running your test and that will probably impact your tests in other ways.